# Как получить текст с Firebase и установить на item из popup menu

Tags: android, firebase

Получить id от item и поставить текст выглядит так

```
popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu1).setTitle("SOMETEXT");
```

Но при вставки текста из FirebaseDatabase приложение вылетает. Как положено получил текст из FirebaseDatabase, но почему-то именно с item проблемы

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference data = databaseReference.child(user.getUid());
    data.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu1).setTitle("sasa");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Покажите код ошибки. Мне кажется проблема не в ФБ...

Comment: попробуйте заменить addValueEventListener на addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: @AndrewGrow
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String  такая ошибка
изменил на addListenerForSingleValueEvent, но всё-равно не сработало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь получить из HashMap строку.
Чтобы решить проблему, вам необходимо использовать модель и получение данных через модель. Например:

1. Создание модели внутри Android-приложения

   ```
   public class UserModel {

       public UserModel() {
           // Default constructor required for calls
       }

       private String name;
       private String email;
       private String photoUri;

       public UserModel(String name, String email, String photoUri) {
           this.name = name;
           this.email = email;
           this.photoUri = photoUri;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Запись модели в `Firebase` выглядит вот так:

[image: Элемент списка]

3. Получение данных по модели. Например, получаем photoUrl:

   ```
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + userId);
   ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           String avatarUri = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class).getPhotoUri();
           //do something with avatarUri
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.e(Constants.LOG, "Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: P.S. извините, почему-то не получается красиво отформатировать код... но он рабочий =)